# Angular 4: JSONP injected script did not invoke callback

Tags: angular, jsonp

I am new to Anguar4 and met this question:

JSONP injected script did not invoke callback

I tried different API for example:
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

However, my api gives me this error. However, it works for jQuery, jsonp. I googled many resources online, spent many hours, but could n't fix it. Here is my code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Jsonp, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ServerService{

    constructor(private jsonp: Jsonp){}

    getServers(term: string) {
                let url = `url`; 
                let params = new URLSearchParams();
                params.set('search', term); // the user's search value
                params.set('action', 'opensearch');
                params.set('format', 'json');
                params.set('callback', 'JSONP_CALLBACK');
                return this.jsonp
               .get(url, { search: params })
               .subscribe(
                (data) => {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                (error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, have you found an answer to this question? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Hi Raef, I think there must be some problems with our API, which possibly does not support JSONP.

Comment: Hi Zichen, thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Hi Raef, thank you so much for keep watching this question for me.

Answer (score 3):

Use  `__ng_jsonp__.__req0.finished`  instead of `JSONP_CALLBACK` !

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Jsonp, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class MyServerService{

    constructor(private jsonp: Jsonp){}

    getServers(term: string) {
                let url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`;

                let params = new URLSearchParams();

                params.set('search', term); // the user's search value
                params.set('action', 'opensearch');
                params.set('format', 'json');
                params.set('callback', '__ng_jsonp__.__req0.finished');

                return this.jsonp
               .get(url, { search: params })
               .subscribe(
                (data) => {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                (error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually solved the problem for me, however the docs state you should use  `JSONP_CALLBACK`  that is replaced by this string `__ng_jsonp____req0_finished` looking at the network call, note the missing "."s. Is this a bug in the angular4 Jsonp module ?

Comment: also note that this will most certainly fail if you need more that one jsonp request

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you are using jsonp ? because you can simply write a service something like,

```
fetchUsers(){
     return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
            .map( response => response.json());
}
```

Comment: Hi John,  it's because there are some cross domain issues with the api

Comment: @ZichenMa: Ah.. that make sense. so are you trying to invoke an API from different URL and process the response ?

Comment: yes, I called an API from my local machine, but the API is hosted on the server. Another reason probably is because of our API is not support JSONP, I have to figure it out from my side, but thank you so much any way.